# C++ create a new number base array

Tags: c++, arrays, radix

Complete noob here.
Trying this in C++.
I am trying to create an array of numbers that are of any base.
That is I want to define a new base and have this array "count" in the new base.
For example: base 78.
I want to create an array of lets say 3 78-base numbers in such a way as when I add to the first "digit" it overflows to the second when it reaches 78.
something like [1] [1] [77] + 1 = [1] [2] [0]...

Is this possible in an efficient way? Can I do this for lets say a 20 long array of base-10000? Or will computation time kill me?

Thanks.

Comment: You should take a look how base conversion is done the right way. http://www.mathsisfun.com/base-conversion-method.html

Comment: Unless you have hardware that works on base 78, you'll have to do the computations in software; and that's of course slower than having specialized hardware optimized to wok with base 2. If that's fast enough depends on your use case. Probably fast enough for a spreadsheet application (where base 10 is more useful than base 2), probably not for a game physics engine.

Comment: don't worry about perfo for now. Write your algo and test it before. Base 10000 will not be a problem here. What is a long array? What are the constraints?

Comment: @ndj I think he means an array of 20 digits in base 10000.  The algorithms are the same for all bases, and are readily available in Knuth (which of course everyone who's programming has).

Comment: @DanielKO A 20 digit number in base 10000 will overflow just about any hardware anyway, so he more or less has to use some sort of software emulation.  On a typical 32 bit machine, using base 10000 _will_ be slower than using base 2^32, however; everyone who does this sort of thing in practice will use a base 2^n, where n is the number of bits in a machine word.  (The algorithms are significantly simpler to implement if you can get twice the digit precision internally, so there is some argument for using a half-word: 32 bit `unsigned int` on a 64 bit machine, for example.)

Comment: @JamesKanze That's pretty much what I said, I tried to address on the performance bit, not on whether it can be done, which seems to be the actual OP's question. It depends on the application, what it does, what are the performance requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of

```
class counter_array {
  public:
    static const int LEN = 20;
    static const int base = 5;

    counter_array operator+=(int inc) {
      arr[0] += inc;
      for (int i = 1; i < LEN; ++i) {
        int old = arr[i];
        arr[i] += arr[i-1] / base;
        arr[i-1] %= base;
        if (arr[i] == old) {
          break;
        }
      }
    }

  private:
    int arr[len];
};
```

I didn't do any debugging, but you should get the drift.

Answer (score 0):

Internally (at least on all modern machines, and all machines
which support C or C++), integral values are binary.  Other
bases are only used for input and output.  Internal operations,
like counting, are "base independent", in the sense that they
depend on the value, and how it is represented.

The question is whether `long long` (at least 64 bits) is big
enough.  If so, you only need to provide conversion routines for
it.  (`strtoll` supports bases up to 36, but there's no
corresponding output routine.)  If not, you'll need to implement
a larger integral type, using the algorithms from Knuth for the
four basic operators.  And you'll need to provide the conversion
routines for the input and output (which are easy once you have
the four basic operations).

You can, of course, use any base for the implementation of your
longer integral type; traditionally, base 2^n, where n is an
available machine word size, has been used, for efficiency
reasons, but there's nothing to stop you from using base 10000,
or any base which will fit into one of the machine words.  Your
numbers will just require more memory (and thus more time); the
algorithms are the same (those in Knuth).